# Is there a way to easily visualize or debug ESL events?

Tags: freeswitch

Freeswitch provides `fs_cli` for this purpose, but the output terribly cluttered.  I'd like to find a way to visualize each one of my call's legs and every ESL event attached to it, eventually with all the values attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this one, pretty useful: https://github.com/pol51/esldebugger

[image: ESL viewer debugger]